# Is it possible to add an IF function within FILTER function?

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to have a condition in a FILTER function to show based on an IF condition

If G1 is open or close, show `'All Jobs'!P2:P=G1` else If G1 is All then do not show condition.

Below is my attempt. But it is not showing any matches. I am guessing my formula is not correct.

```
=FILTER('All Jobs'!A2:P,'All Jobs'!B2:B>=B1,'All Jobs'!B2:B<=D1,'All Jobs'!G2:G=F1&
IF(((G1="Open")+(G1="Closed")),","&'All Jobs'!P2:P=G1,G1="All",""))
```

Comment: Please share a copy of your spreadsheet

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cpI-euw57m1RLHwf0YPZA-V_ZNzLw8Ti5HDQwm_GKbs/edit?usp=sharing) I would like to filter 'Month Report'!F1 (Local, Overseas) and 'Month Report'!G1 (Open, Closed, All)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can use:

```
REGEXMATCH('All Jobs'!G2:G, "Open|Closed")
```